# Unable to complete this operation.  Please contact your administrator

Tags: 2007, administration, database, error

We are using one API SharepointImporter Tool to upload documents to a SharePoint Site. When we are uploading one archive file we are getting the following problem.

**Error:**

Unable to complete this operation.  Please contact your administrator.

```
StackTrace:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.PutFile(String bstrUrl, String 
bstrWebRelativeUrl, Object varFile, PutFileOpt PutFileOpt, String bstrCreatedBy, String 
bstrModifiedBy, Int32 iCreatedByID, Int32 iModifiedByID, Object varTimeCreated, Object 
varTimeLastModified, Object varProperties, String bstrCheckinComment, UInt32& 
pdwVirusCheckStatus, String& pVirusCheckMessage)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileCollection.AddInternal(String urlOfFile, Object file, 
PutFileOpt fileOpt, String createdBy, String modifiedBy, Int32 createdByID, Int32 
modifiedByID, DateTime timeCreated, DateTime timeLastModified, Object varProperties, String 
checkInComment, SPVirusCheckStatus& virusCheckStatus, String& virusCheckMessage)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileCollection.Add(String urlOfFile, Stream stream, Boolean 
overwrite, String checkInComment, Boolean checkRequiredFields, SPVirusCheckStatus& 
virusCheckStatus, String& virusCheckMessage)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileCollection.Add(String urlOfFile, Stream stream, Boolean 
overwrite, String checkInComment, Boolean checkRequiredFields)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileCollection.Add(String urlOfFile, Stream stream, Boolean 
overwrite)
   at SharePoint_Importer.SP_OtherFile.Add_attachFile(String Sitepath, XmlNode xmlNd)
```

**Configuration:**

We have 190GB of free space where the content DB is sitting. We have this problem only for one archive only. We running the different set of archival to the same content DB (site collection) and the archival is running fine till now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution.

There is case that if any one using sql express edition ,it supports 4 GB max size. They is no limitation if they use full version of sql server.My client using express edition....

Comment: If you use SQL Server 2008 R2 Express Edition the limit is upped to 10GB.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar error with as useless an error message. It could be a permissions problem. I've found that often times when you get the "Unable to complete this operation" message, it's because you don't have permissions to do what you're trying to do. I would check what permissions your application is using and possibly use elevated permissions for that operation instead. Or maybe open up the permissions on the archive giving you problems.

---- Edit ----

I've also recently seen a lot of strange permissions behavior regarding inheriting permissions from a parent site. You might try dis-inheriting permissions (or re-inheriting depending on your current setting) and see if that makes a difference.